# Eigenvalues of product of diagonal positive matrix and symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues

Assume that we have two real symmetric matrices A and B, where A is a positive diagonal matrix, and B is a symmetric matrix with one eigenvalue λ = 0. Assume that H= AB;
is it possible to proof that the matrix H has the same properties than B (semi-positive, negative or indefinite matrix)? That is means the eigenvalues of H have the same signe than the eigenvalues of B.

Comment: First, the product $AB$ is not symmetric in general, so its eigenvalues could be complex.

Answer (score 6):

The eigenvalues of $H$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}$.
See [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).